# split XML in several sites using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, split, xslt-2.0

I know this have been asked so often and I checked all the posts but still I dont get it. I have the following situation: I am working on a letter edition that consists of 30 xml files, each letter in one xml file. Each of the xml file includes a .png of the original letter (pic / site). I wrote a XSLT Stylesheet to convert all the XML into html.  In the end my html looks like that: on the left site are the pics, on the right site is the transcription, the text.
every letter has different amount of sites. I now want to split every letter per page, so that every new page is in a seperate html file (including the single pic).

so my XML looks like ( I am working with TEI):

```
<TEIHeader>...</TEIHeader> 
<text>
<body>

  <div type="letter">
    <pb n="1" type="front"/>
    <div> here is the text of my first site of the letter</div>


<pb n="2" type="back"/>
<div> here is the text of my second site of the letter </div>
```

and so on...

p.e. the html of my 2nd page should look like that:

```
    <img src="01.januar.1910.2.png" alt="brief 1.2" width="100%" />
     <div class="fright margin-left">

           <p class="seitenzahl">-2-</p>
          text of my 2nd site of the letter
           </p>
```

I thought about using

```
<xsl:template match="node()[following::tei:pb[@n = '2']]">
```

to get the 2nd site of the xml (just for the text) using

```
<xsl:result-document>
```

I either managed to overwrite my existing file (p.e. 04.html) or I got the message "cannot write more than one result document to the same uri" (I work with Oxygen, Saxon-PE 9.4.0.6)

For the pictures my XML looks like that:

```
<facsimile>
<graphic url="01.januar.1910.1.png" n="1"/>
<graphic url="01.januar.1910.2.png" n="2"/>
</facsimile>
```

So there are different problems:

- The different letters have different number of pages
- For every page I want to creat a new html file (with a new name)
  The file names are always Numberoftheletter_ML.xml (p.e. 01_ML.xml /01_ML.html, 02_ML.xml and so on) and I want for every new page 01_ML_1.html, 01_ML_2.html, etc.

I tried to do the following with result-document, but it overwrites my original letter (01_ML.html):

```
 <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.html"  method="html" >
```

It would be great if someone can help me. If you need more code I can update (its just so much code till now)

UPDATE: 
This is my XSLT for creating new doc.

```
 <xsl:template match="node()[following::tei:pb[@n = '2']]">
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="generate-id()"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:result-document href="///D:/directory/{$filename}2_ML.html"  method="html" >

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.5.css" />


                <title>Letters (1910 - 1914)</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<xsl:result-document href="file://directory/{$filename}.html"  method="html" >` with `directory` replaced with your real full directory, e.g. `C:/`

Comment: um, try `file:///` instead of `file://`

Comment: that works with the ///! But still it says:can not write more then one result to the same URI. when I use generate-id() it overwrites my document

Comment: OK, we will need to see some more code then. Like, how you are generating `filename`.

Comment: I am not sure how it works correctly I tried: `<xsl:variable name="filename" select="generate-id()>´ might be wrong

Comment: I need to see the context of where you are doing this. Can you update your question with the xsl:result-document and the xsl:result-document with their surrounding lines please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `<xsl:template match="node()[following::tei:pb[@n = '2']]">` is not what you want. The template matches every node which has a following tei:pb[@n = '2']. In your example, these are TEIHeader/text(), TEIHeader/text/text(), TEIHeader/text/body/text(), body/div/pb, body/div/div, and the three body/div/text(). But this does'nt explain why generate-id generates the same id more than once, which suggests that the template ist invoked more than once for the same node. Take a look at your `apply-templates` statements.